# Animating a DIV automatically

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

http://jsfiddle.net/AndyMP/fVKDy/

This fiddle illustrates a problem I am trying to solve. The container DIV accommodates two DIVs which are animated across. The second DIV has a smaller height than the first because there is less content. What I am trying to do is get the bottom DIV to slide up automatically according to the height of the content in the second DIV when it is visible. But it slides up and over the second DIV.

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

```
$(function() {
    $(".left_slide").click(function() {
        $(".block1").stop(true, true).animate({ left: -400 }, 500).hide(1000);
        $(".block2").stop(true, true).animate({ left: 0 }, 500);
    });
});
$(function() {    
    $(".right_slide").click(function() {
        $(".block2").stop(true, true).animate({ left: 400 }, 500);
        $(".block1").stop(true, true).animate({ left: 0 }, 500);
    });
});
```

CSS

```
#blog_slide_container {
position: relative;
width: 400px;
z-index: 5;
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid #000;
}
.block1 {
position: relative;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 400px;
z-index: 6;
background-color: #333;
color: #FFF;
}
.block2 {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 400px;
width: 400px;
z-index: 6;
background-color: #CCC;
color: #FFF;
}
#bottom_container {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 100%;
height: 280px;
z-index: 3;
background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure where to start on this one. The approach is wrong. Do not position your outside element with position absolute. Don't animate each element. Instead wrap both in a div and animate just that div. Then you can measure the height of the active slide and move the footer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
Check my updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/fVKDy/9/)

Added code to dynamically change the container height.

Check animated version http://jsfiddle.net/skram/fVKDy/17/

Another version.. http://jsfiddle.net/skram/fVKDy/16/ <-- Difference is that the left/right shift happens after the bottom blocks slides up/down.

---

Check the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/fVKDy/6/) demo.

Two things,

1. Added a fixed height to the `#blog_slide_container`. When you animate, the position of the animating div becomes `absolute` and so the container re-sizes itself to `0 height`.
2. Added show on `block1` when right is clicked.

Comment: What I'm after is no white space. I want the bottom container to slide up so it sits directly under either DIV without a space between the two.

Comment: Checking it out right now, thanks. Any chance of making the bottom slide up, otherwise it's perfect.

Comment: @Andy I was making that.. :) Animated version http://jsfiddle.net/skram/fVKDy/12/

Comment: Insanely good. I'll try and break down what you've done! Thanks again.

Comment: Dang, I feel like I'm being super picky here. Is it just me or does the first DIV disappear as opposed to sliding left?

Comment: @Andy: No you are right.. Since it was in the Original, I thought that is how you wanted it.. Check the updated links in the post.

Answer (score 1):

This is it... i guess -> http://jsfiddle.net/fVKDy/13/
Both parts are working here.
Just put another wrapper to your blocks and delete those position relatives. The only non static positioning you need is on the additional wrapper.

---

Here is another version. http://jsfiddle.net/fVKDy/5/
Iam going to tweak it a bit more..

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/fVKDy/11/

I will come back shortly and edit in an explanation (have to run).  But basically I added an inner container which is animated instead of the elements themselves.

Comment: The first part works perfectly. When the second DIV slides back out, I'm not seeing the first one slide back in.

Comment: Right, I had only done the one direction, the other would be similar.

Comment: Believe it or not I actually tried to get it to work the other way around and failed :(