# DIV animation, sliding issue

Tags: jquery, animation

http://jsfiddle.net/fVKDy/11/

I'm looking to fix this animation if possible. The first part works perfectly, the DIV slides left to reveal more content with the DIV below sliding up. The reverse doesn't because the content DIV doesn't display properly and the DIV below doesn't slide back down.

Any help is appreciated.

It is a continuation of this discussion from yesterday [Animating a DIV automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234550/animating-a-div-automatically)

```
     $(function() {
$(".left_slide").click(function() {
    $("#inner_container").stop(true, true).animate({ left: -400 }, 500, function(){
        $(".block1").stop(true, true).animate({height: "1px"},1000);
    })
});
});
$(function() {    
$(".right_slide").click(function() {
    $("#inner_container").stop(true, true).animate({ left: 0 }, 500, function(){
        $(".block1").stop(true, true).animate({height: "1px"},1000);
    })
});
});
```

CSS

```
#blog_slide_container {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
width: 400px;
z-index: 5;
border: 1px solid #000;
}

#inner_container{
position: relative;
width: 2000px;   
}

.block1 {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 400px;
z-index: 6;
background-color: #333;
color: #FFF;
}
.block2 {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 400px;
z-index: 6;
background-color: #333;
color: #FFF;
}
#bottom_container {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 100%;
height: 280px;
z-index: 3;
background-color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orig/fVKDy/18/):

```
$(function() {
    var block1_h = 0;
    $(".left_slide").click(function() {
        $("#inner_container").stop(true, true).animate({
            left: -400
        }, 500, function() {
            block1_h = $(".block1").stop(true, true).animate({
                height: "1px"
            }, 1000).height();
        })
    });
    $(".right_slide").click(function() {
        $(".block1").stop(true, true).animate({
            height: block1_h
        }, 1000, function() {
            $("#inner_container").stop(true, true).animate({
                left: 0
            }, 500);
        });
    });
});
```

I just kept the original `.block1` height in a variable. That way I could completely reverse the order of animation.

Comment: You dont need to store the height in vars, you could use "toggle" in that case -> http://jsfiddle.net/fVKDy/13 – danwit

Comment: The problem is that `toggle` hides the div when the animation's done, thereby making `#inner_container`'s `left: -400px` shift `block2` out of sight (because `block1` is not displaying its 400px any more). I figured saving the `height` is quicker than adjusting `#inner_container`'s left back to 0 and then back to -400 on `.right_side` click

Comment: I just recognized that my fiddle was broken. I forgot to switch the outer container back to `left: 0` .. damn you chromium repaint algorithm :)

Answer (score 0):

I thought we've fixed it yesterday [Animating a DIV automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234550/animating-a-div-automatically/9234756#9234756)

Take this http://jsfiddle.net/skram/fVKDy/17/